# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12.04.4 with wubi

Tags: wubi, system-installation

Hey I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 64 bit with Wubi and I am facing 2 problems

So I downloaded Ubuntu iso and Wubi of same versions

After that I pasted both Ubuntu iso and Wubi in same folder and than started installation on my `C:` disk and its installed without any error and then I rebooted and when the ubuntu opens it's showing a error that "no root filesystem found". So thats my first problem.

Now I am gonna talk about my 2nd problem. In this I tried to install Ubuntu with Wubi in other hard disk partitions like `D:` `F:` and while I was installing through wubi its gives me error that is given below

> Error executing command
>
> ```
> command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {8bad8de1-974c-11e3-9803-d1f0e415df87} device partition=E:
>
> retval=1
>
> stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
> ```
>
> The request is not supported.

Plz help me

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, it means Wubi failed while trying to include that latest Ubuntu installation in the boot options of Windows. If you check [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F), you'll see that while MANUALLY uninstalling an Ubuntu distro, you'll need to REMOVE Ubuntu from your boot options by editing bcdedit.exe. So, you're getting this error while trying to ADD Ubuntu to your boot options.
In order to solve this, I suggest you start off by uninstalling the first Ubuntu and then start afresh using Wubi. Or, though I'm not an expert on this, do a dual-boot installation using a bootable USB drive or some other method. (See [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for details.) Goodluck!